# How to use the condition with other rows (previous moments in time series data), in pandas, python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a pandas.dataframe `df`. It is a time series data, with 1000 rows and 3 columns. What I want is given in the pseudo-code below.

```
for each row
    if the value in column 'colA' at [this_row-1] is higher than 
    the value in column 'B' at [this_row-2] for more than 3%
        then set the value in 'colCheck' at [this_row] as True.

Finally, pickout all the rows in the df where 'colCheck' are True.
```

I will use the following example to further demonstrate my purpose.

```
 df =     
             'colA', 'colB', 'colCheck'
 Dates
 2017-01-01,     20,     30,      NAN
 2017-01-02,     10,     40,      NAN
 2017-01-03,     50,     20,     False
 2017-01-04,     40,     10,      True
```

First, when `this_row = 2` (the 3rd row, where the date is 2017-01-03), the value in `colA` at [this_row-1] is `10`, the value in `colB` at [this_row-2] is `30`. So `(10-30)/30 = -67% < 3%`, so the value in `colCheck` at [this_row] is False.

Likewise, when `this_row = 3`,  `(50-40)/40 = 25% > 3%`, so the value in `colCheck` at [this_row] is True.

Last but not least, the first two rows in `colCheck` should be NAN, since the calculation needs to access [this_row-2] in `colB`. But the first two rows do not have [this_row-2].

Besides, the criteria of `3%` and [row-1] in `colA`, [row-2] in `colB` are just examples. In my real project, they are situational, e.g. `4%` and [row-3].

I am looking for concise and elegant approach. I am using Python3.

Thanks.

Comment: You could have posted the expected output in the form of a dataframe right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rearrange the maths and use `pd.Series.shift`

```
df.colA.shift(1).div(df.colB.shift(2)).gt(1.03)

Dates
2017-01-01    False
2017-01-02    False
2017-01-03    False
2017-01-04     True
dtype: bool
```

---

Using `pd.DataFrame.assign` we can create a copy with the new column

```
df.assign(colCheck=df.colA.shift(1).div(df.colB.shift(2)).gt(1.03))

            colA  colB  colCheck
Dates                           
2017-01-01    20    30     False
2017-01-02    10    40     False
2017-01-03    50    20     False
2017-01-04    40    10      True
```

---

If you insisted on leaving the first two as `NaN`, you could use `iloc`

```
df.assign(colCheck=df.colA.shift(1).div(df.colB.shift(2)).gt(1.03).iloc[2:])

            colA  colB colCheck
Dates                          
2017-01-01    20    30      NaN
2017-01-02    10    40      NaN
2017-01-03    50    20    False
2017-01-04    40    10     True
```

---

And for maximum clarity:

```
# This creates a boolean array of when your conditions are met
colCheck = (df.colA.shift(1) / df.colB.shift(2)) > 1.03
# This chops off the first two `False` values and creates a new
# column named `colCheck` and assigns to it the boolean values
# calculate just above.
df.assign(colCheck=colCheck.iloc[2:])

            colA  colB colCheck
Dates                          
2017-01-01    20    30      NaN
2017-01-02    10    40      NaN
2017-01-03    50    20    False
2017-01-04    40    10     True
```